# parse_duration (trino) fuction in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, parsing, duration, trino

I have  duration field, like 21,600 seconds, and I would like to change it to timestamp duration to be able to add it to another timestamps.
In Trino I was able to use

```
parse_duration(concat(cast(cast(update_interval as int) as varchar),'s'))
```

, but I cannot get in PostgreSQL.

Shared on a pic the goal:
[image]

Anyone has done the same? thanks!!

Comment: What's your data type for "duration field"? Would you like to change it on the fly as we can see from example, or change the storage structure and re-parse the already stored data? Please edit your question and add more information (MVCE) - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks @KamilGosciminski.  It is strange. But it seems and int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your original data is/can be cast to integer, so you can try using [`make_interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.15.6.2.2.28.1.1.1):

```sql
select make_interval(secs => 10)
```

To get desired output you can try something like the following:

```sql
select to_char(justify_hours(make_interval(secs => update_interval)), 'DD HH24:MI:SS')
from (select 2592000 as update_interval) t
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6BeU8HmL2jGshPYrhgHaQv/1)

Comment: I could not make that work. I share a pic on the description for more clarify of the goal. Thanks!!